# grails - domain class can not be found

Tags: grails

I have domain `User` (in domain dir) and controller `UserController` (in controller dir).

I have also controller `AdminController` (in controller/admin dir).

I would like to use User class in `AdminController`. When I am doing it I have exception that User class can not be found.

So here we have a question. Does `AdminController` should be able to use User domain or maybe only `UserController` is able to use User domain?

Let me know what do you think about this and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the package of AdminController is different from User, you'll need to import the class.  For example:

```
import User

class AdminController {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was trying this as first step :) but it does not work and than I was suprised :)